# Updating image stop updating if not found

Tags: javascript

I am fetching an image from a camera and updating it every second with the following:

```
<img id="myImage" style="width: 100%" src="<%= EVERCAM_API %>cameras/<%= @camera['id'] %>/snapshot.jpg?api_id=<%= current_user.api_id %>&api_key=<%= current_user.api_key %>" />

<script type="text/javascript">

var int_time = setInterval(function() {
var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
myImageElement.src = '<%= EVERCAM_API %>cameras/<%= @camera["id"] %>/snapshot.jpg?api_id=<%= current_user.api_id %>&api_key=<%= current_user.api_key %>&rand=' + new Date().getTime();
}, 1000);

</script>
```

The problem is if for a period I can't get an image from the camera I get a broken image. What I want to happen is that if I don't get an updated image - that the image doesn't try to refresh.
I have made an attempt along the lines of the following but I just can't quite get it to work:

```
var jQuery,
url = '<%= EVERCAM_API %>cameras/<%= @camera["id"] %>/snapshot.jpg?api_id=<%=   current_user.api_id %>&api_key=<%= current_user.api_key %>&rand=' + new Date().getTime();',
refresh = 1000,
priv = <%= params[:private] %>,
iframeStyle = "width: 100%; height:100%;",
imgStyle = "width: 100%;";

function updateImage() {
if (refresh > 0) {
  window.ec_watcher = setTimeout(updateImage, refresh);
}
jQuery("<img style='" + imgStyle + "'/>").attr('src', url + '?' + new Date().getTime())
  .load(function() {
    if (!this.complete || this.naturalWidth === undefined || this.naturalWidth === 0) {
      console.log('broken image!');
    } else {
      container.empty().append(jQuery(this))
      console.log('updated');
    }
  });
}
```

I'm just having trouble actually getting the second idea to work!

Comment: What way is it not working? You do realise there's an extra `'` a the end of the second line?

Comment: don't update the "this is displayed to the user" image, then. create a new img object that's not part of the dom, do the `.src` stuff on that, confirm it loaded ok, THEN insert that image into the dom. No img gets loaded, you just keep displaying the old/original one.